# Match and remove duplicated characters: Replace multiple (3+) non-consecutive occurrences

Tags: python, r, regex, string, replace

I am looking for a `regex` pattern that will match third, fourth, ... occurrence of each character. Look below for clarification:

For example I have the following string:

```
111aabbccxccybbzaa1
```

I want to replace all the duplicated characters after the second occurrence. The output will be:

```
11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

***Some regex patterns that I tried so far:***

Using the following regex I can find the last occurrence of each character:

[`(.)(?=.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/zdajMW/2)

Or using this one I can do it for consecutive duplicates but not for any duplicates:

[`([a-zA-Z1-9])\1{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/zdajMW/6/)

Comment: What regex engine do you plan to use with the regex?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `r` is the preferred one. `Python` or `PHP` work as well.

Comment: You can only do that with a regex that supports infinite width lookbehind, so your only option is Python PyPi regex module then. Use it with `(.)(?<=^(?:(?:(?!\1).)*\1){2,}(?:(?!\1).)*\1)` regex. [Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.%29%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c1%29.%29*%5c1%29%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c1%29.%29*%5c1%29&i=111aabbccxccybbzaa1&r=-).

Comment: See https://rextester.com/ANLC41094, install PyPi regex using `pip install regex`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is that better than `(.)(?<=(.*\1){3})`?

Comment: @StefanPochmann Well, `(.)(?<=(?:.*\1){3})` will do the job, too, but all these are not good since excessive backtracking may cause issues with longer strings. I'd rather write a non-regex method to solve the problem.

Comment: @StefanPochmann If by "better" you meant  peformance, my regex will perform faster if the matches are close to the start of string and there are a lot of no matches at the end of the string and your variant will perform better if there are matches close to the end of the string, and the length of the string is considerable. My regex has "linear" logic, matching subpattern sequences that are mutually exclusive, and in the `(.*\1)` pattern, `.` can match what `\1` matches, which adds to the overall complexity.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yours can probably be improved to `(.)(?<=(?:\1.*?){2}\1)`

Comment: @bobblebubble Lazy and greedy `.` in real life are the same as far as performance is concerned unless you are sure where matches will occur (closer to the end or start of the string), but we usually are not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If I copy the teststring into regexstorm several times, making it a huge string, I get performance difference eg your pattern 750ms, `(.)(?<=(?:.*\1){3})` 25ms, `(.)(?<=(?:\1.*?){2}\1)` 3ms. You can just test yourself. Yours seem to be the least efficient pattern and it's hardest to read.

Comment: @bobblebubble My regex was work in progress. You both took it from there. Next, copying the same string is a wrong test case. You need to test with strings where matches occur within different distance between matches.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non-regex R solution. Split string. Replace elements of this vector having rowid >= 3 * with `'-'`. Paste it back together.

```
x <- '111aabbccxccybbzaa1'

xsplit <- strsplit(x, '')[[1]]
xsplit[data.table::rowid(xsplit) >= 3] <- '-'
paste(xsplit, collapse = '')

# [1] "11-aabbccx--y--z---"
```

* `rowid(x)` is an integer vector with each element representing the number of times the value from the corresponding element of `x` has been realized. So if the last element of `x` is `1`, and that's the fourth time `1` has occurred in `x`, the last element of `rowid(x)` is `4`.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily accomplish this without regex:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##PY1NCsMgEIXX8RSzM0G6sN0JnkRmMYppB4oJTgJNL291093je3/7dby28mhNwIO21hLFmNInpSvGL5HVSq1bhRO4gORjlsWpaRAeJDD8daXyzPM7l55ZgFeQwOj9ieHusJemcSHBMRp906a7xjpUaq9cxm5rPw)

```
s = '111aabbccxccybbzaa1'

for u in set(s):
    for i in [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i]==u][2:]:
        s = s[:i]+'-'+s[i+1:]

print(s)
```

Result:

```
11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

---

How this works:

1. `for u in set(s)` gets a list of unique characters in the string: `{'c','a','b','y','1','z','x'}`
2. `for i in ...` loops over the indices that we gather in 3.
3. `[i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i]==u][2:]` loops over each character in the string and checks if it matches `u` (from step 1.), then it slices the array from the 2nd element to the end (dropping the first two elements if they exist)
4. Set the string to `s[:i]+'-'+s[i+1:]` - concatenate the substring up to the index with `-` and then the substring after the index, effectively omitting the original character.

Answer (score 3):

An option with `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) if (count >=3) '-' else x)
for(i in c(0:9, letters)) x <- gsubfn(i, p, x)
x
#[1] "11-aabbccx--y--z---"
```

#### data

```
x <- '111aabbccxccybbzaa1'
```

Answer (score 2):

No regex python one-liner:

```py
s = "111aabbccxccybbzaa1"

print("".join(char if s.count(char, 0, i) < 2 else "-" for i, char in enumerate(s)))
# ==> "11-aabbccx--y--z---"
```

This enumerates through the string, counting occurrences of the current character behind it and only putting the character if it is one of the first 2, otherwise dash.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it with `pandas`.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = '111aabbccxccybbzaa1'
# 11-aabbccx--y--z---

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': list(s)})
df['Count'] = 1
df['cumsum'] = df[['Data', 'Count']].groupby('Data').cumsum()
df.loc[df['cumsum']>=3, 'Data'] = '-'
''.join(df.Data.to_list())
```

**Output**:

```
11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Thanks to *Wiktor Stribiżew*, *Stefan Pochmann*, and *bobble bubble*. For the sake of completion, I am posting possible `regex` solutions discussed in the comments;</sub>

This is only doable with a regex that supports infinite width lookbehind. Using Python PyPi regex module we can do the followings:

```py
#python 2.7.12
import regex

s = "111aabbccxccybbzaa1"
```

```
print(regex.sub(r'(.)(?<=^(?:(?:(?!\1).)*\1){2,}(?:(?!\1).)*\1)', '-', s)) #Wiktor Stribizew
     ## 11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

```
print(regex.sub(r'(.)(?<=(.*\1){3})', '-', s)) #Stefan Pochmann
     ## 11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

```
print(regex.sub(r'(.)(?<=(?:.*\1){3})', '-', s)) #Wiktor Stribizew
     ## 11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

```
print(regex.sub(r'(.)(?<=(?:\1.*?){2}\1)', '-', s)) #bobble bubble
     ## 11-aabbccx--y--z---
```

[See code in use.](https://rextester.com/SLX49603).